# Cannot invoke observeForever on a background thread while testing viewmodel and livadata

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel, android-livedata

i'm trying to test my viewmodel along with livedata , i have set up the testing class and the code but i still receive an error that i cannot invoke observeForever on a background thread , i don't know what wrong am i doing , can anyone provide some help please , Thank you

- This is my viewmodel

```
class SimpleViewModel constructor(
    var simpleRepository: SimpleRepository
): ViewModel() {


    fun observeItems(): LiveData<List<ItemsModel>> {
        return simpleRepository.getItems()
    }

    fun addItem(itemsModel: ItemsModel) = viewModelScope.launch {
        simpleRepository.insertItems(itemsModel)
    }

}
```

- This is my testing class

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
@SmallTest
class SimpleViewModelTest {


    @get:Rule
    val instantTaskExecutorRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()
    private lateinit var context: Context
    private lateinit var simpleViewModel: SimpleViewModel
    private lateinit var simpleRepository: SimpleRepository
    private lateinit var itemsDao: ItemsDao

    @Before
    fun setUp(){
        context = ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext()
        val db = Room.inMemoryDatabaseBuilder(context,ItemsDatabase::class.java)
            .allowMainThreadQueries().build()
        itemsDao = db.itemsDao()
        simpleRepository = SimpleRepository(itemsDao)
        simpleViewModel = SimpleViewModel(simpleRepository)
    }


    @After
    fun tearDown(){

    }

    @Test
    fun testCaseDataIsNotNull() = runBlockingTest {
        val itemsModel = ItemsModel("Car",12.500F,"California",1)
        simpleViewModel.addItem(itemsModel)
        val allItems = simpleViewModel.observeItems().getOrAwaitValue()
        assertThat(allItems).contains(itemsModel)
    }


}
```

- Error Capture
  [image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom rule the named mainCoroutineRule.

```
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
 class MainCoroutineRule : TestWatcher(), TestCoroutineScope by TestCoroutineScope() {

override fun starting(description: Description) {
    super.starting(description)
   Dispatchers.setMain(this.coroutineContext[ContinuationInterceptor] as CoroutineDispatcher)
}

override fun finished(description: Description) {
    super.finished(description)
    Dispatchers.resetMain()
}

 }
```

And use this rule inside test class

```
ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
@get:Rule
var mainCoroutineRule = MainCoroutineRule()
```

[Sample](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/blob/master/LiveDataSample/app/src/test/java/com/android/example/livedatabuilder/util/MainCoroutineRule.kt)

Comment: I have added the code above , and still showing the same error , I'm allowing testing on mainthread since i'm not gonna do any mutlti threading , MainCoroutineRule() should handle that , but still the same error ..